# Select given combination of values in one column

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a trouble writing this script in a given way. 
Let's say we have a table with two columns: `entity` and `attribute`. 
`attribute` has a static number of possible values, say 1 to 10. One `entity` can only have 1 row for each `attribute` value (entity `a` can't have attribute `8` two times). 
How do I select only those `entities`, which only have `attribute` values 2 and 6 (both of them)?

Comment: Oh, the joys of the [Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV)](http://tonyandrews.blogspot.co.uk/2004/10/otlt-and-eav-two-big-design-mistakes.html) "data model"!

Comment: I was going to submit an answer for you but @sstan beat me to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood your statement correctly:

```
select t1.entity
from your_table t1
join your_table t2
  on t1.entity = t2.entity
 and t2.attribute = 6
where t1.attribute = 2
and not exists (
    select null
    from your_table t3
    where t3.entity = t1.entity
    and t3.attribute not in (2,6)
);
```

The above not only makes sure to only give you entities that have both `2` and `6` attributes, but it also makes sure it doesn't have any other attributes besides those 2.  That's what I understood from your problem statement.

**EDIT**

Here is another, simpler way that relies on the fact that you cannot have duplicate attribute entries.

```
select entity
from your_table
where attribute in (2,6)
group by entity
having count(*) = 2;
```

If you need to check 3 attributes, just adjust the `IN` clause to add your 3rd value, and change the `having count(*)` clause to check against `3` instead of `2`.

Comment: You understood me correctly and this does exactly what I was asking, thanks. But what if I have 3 attributes to check? In this case I have to join 3 times. Maybe there is a more efficient way...

Comment: If you are 100% sure that you can never have duplicate attribute records, then there is a way to simplify the query so that you can more easily check  for a variable number of attributes.  I'll edit my answer to include the alternative.

Comment: hah, the second one is JUST what i've been using (and found some broken data, btw...). I think I'll stick with the 1st one... Thanks a lot for enlightenment ;-)

Comment: If you have broken data, then, even with the first query, you may want to add a `DISTINCT` (`select distinct t1.entity`) to avoid listing the same entity multiple times, which is possible with duplicate attribute rows.